# could not convert string to float: 'no reading'

Tags: python, series

I was trying to convert the data types in a series from object to float.
values_int=values[:].astype(float)
But it returned the following:
could not convert string to float: 'no reading'

Comment: the error tells your clearly, that you cannot convert the string `'no reading'` into a float.

Comment: but i do not have a string names 'no reading', the array contains only numbers

Comment: ok, do `print(values[:])` and post the content of what it prints in the screen

Comment: check for isnumeric( similar function) and then convert.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. There could be missing values.
2. There could be (e.g., 10.2 or 10,2)
   Check the data and make sure that there are no inconsistencies.
   Also would be helpful to see an example of the string that you're trying to convert into a float.

Comment: I have the data as numbers but their type is object plus some include 'no reading' for no data. The problem is that I am not being able to convert the data into float because of the 'no reading' cells!

Comment: You could iterate and see where the issue is, by using (except).
Would be helpful if you could provide a sample/example of the data?

Also your questions was: "could not convert string to float...